How to implement a button in html to toggle between two different views
I am struggling to implement a button on the client side of an html page that would allow the user toggling between two different layouts invoked through corresponding view components. Here is what I started:
@{
    bool display = Request.Form["display"] == "true";
}

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="display" value="@display.ToString().ToLower()" />
    Display: 
    <button type="submit">
        @(display ? "Layout 2" : "Layout 1")
    </button>
</form>

@if (display)
{
    <div>
        <!-- First view component -->
        <h2>Layout 1</h2>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div>
        <!-- Second view component -->
        <h2>Layout 2</h2>
    </div>
}

I have an error message upon loading the page: "This request does not have a content-type header. Forms are available from requests with bodies like POSTs and a form content-type of either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multi-part/form-data".
I have tried to amend the <form> with the attribute enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or enctype="multi-part/form-data" with no success. I have also tried to declare the boolean variable "display" as
@{
    bool display = false;
    if (Request.Method == "POST")
    {
        display = Request.Form["display"] == "true";
    }
}

bu then, the variable never gets amended upon clicking on the button, thereby showing that the statement Request.Method == "POST" is false in general, since it turns out that, actually, Request.Method == "GET", in spite of the <form> attribute method="post".
